# PySpark DataFrame Windowing Partitioning with a condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample DataFrame with an "id" column and a "time' column.
I want to derive 3 new columns.

1. Distinct Count of "time" that is related to "id"
2. Distinct Count of "time" overall.
3. Distinct Count of overall "time" that comes on or after the first occurrence of "id"

I think I have the 1 & 2 figured out.
I need help with the third.
For item 3. The values for the corresponding "id" should be as below

- 1@ (20)
- 2@ (18)
- 3@ (11)

  My Code Sample:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
  df = (sc.parallelize([
          { "id":"1@" ,"time":"2018-09-13" },
          { "id":"1@" ,"time":"2018-09-14" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-17" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-18" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-19" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-20" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-21" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-22" },
          { "id":"2@" ,"time":"2018-10-23" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-09" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-10" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-11" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-12" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-13" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-14" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-15" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-16" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-17" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-18" },
          { "id":"3@" ,"time":"2018-11-19" }

    ]).toDF()
    .cache()
   )

  (
  df
  .withColumn
  (
      'min',
      F.min('time')
      .over
      (
          Window.partitionBy
          (
              F.col('id')
          )

      )
  )
  .withColumn
  (
      'group_size',
      F.size
      (
          F.collect_set('time')
          .over
          (
              Window.partitionBy
              (
                  F.col('id')
              )
          )
      )
  )
  .withColumn
  (
      'overall_size',
      F.size
      (
          F.collect_set('time')
          .over
          (
              Window.partitionBy
              (

              )
          )
      )
  )
  .withColumn
  (
      'overall_size_from_first_group_appearance',
      F.size
      (
          F.collect_set
          (
              F.when
              (
                  F.min('time')
                  .over
                  (
                      Window.partitionBy
                      (
                        F.col('id') 
                      )
                  )
                  <=
                  F.col('time'),
                  F.col('time')
              )
          )
          .over
          (
              Window.partitionBy
              (

              )
          )

      )
  )
  .orderBy
  (
      F.col('time').asc()
  )
  .show(truncate = False)
  )
  ```

[image]

It is the final column in the screen capture that I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Here will be my attack on this question:

```
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.col('time').desc())))
df = df.withColumn('overall_size_from_first_group_appearance', F.max('rank').over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time')))

df.show()
```

The outputs are like below:

```
+---+----------+----+----------------------------------------+
| id|      time|rank|overall_size_from_first_group_appearance|
+---+----------+----+----------------------------------------+
| 1@|2018-09-13|  20|                                      20|
| 1@|2018-09-14|  19|                                      20|
| 2@|2018-10-17|  18|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-18|  17|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-19|  16|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-20|  15|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-21|  14|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-22|  13|                                      18|
| 2@|2018-10-23|  12|                                      18|
| 3@|2018-11-09|  11|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-10|  10|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-11|   9|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-12|   8|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-13|   7|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-14|   6|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-15|   5|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-16|   4|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-17|   3|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-18|   2|                                      11|
| 3@|2018-11-19|   1|                                      11|
+---+----------+----+----------------------------------------+
```

Hope it helps!